# Can't Code in C# on Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, xamarin, f#

This may sound stupid, but I'm a new Xamarin Studio user and for some reason I can't code in C# on my Mac? It only allows me to code in F#.

Comment: I would consider that a feature.

Comment: When you create a project, you will have an dropdown option for the language of that project that is to the right of the project type: `C#` or `F#`. Of course @s952163 has a great point, a F#-only world would be a grand world ;-)

Comment: @SushiHangover - please would you add that as an answer rather than have it buried in a comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Xamarin Studio, or Visual Studio for Mac (VS4M), when you create a project, you will have an dropdown option for the language of that project that is to the right of the project type: `C#` or `F#` or even `IL` (depending upon project type).

[image]

Choose:

- `C#` for normal programmers
- `F#` for programmers who really hate classes
- `IL` is only for real programmers, if you have to ask.... ;-)

If those language options are not available, review the Language binding `Addins` (`Extensions` on VS4M) to ensure that each of those languages are enabled:

[image]

Comment: `C# for normal programmers; F# for programmers who really hate classes` it sounds a little unfair.

Comment: Loved the way you explained the different language options.